# Visual Studio 2015 - Store menu disabled/missing for new Blank Universal App C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing a frustrating behaviour of VS2015 Community under Windows 10.

When I create a simple Universal Blank App C# after launching and testing the code the Store menu to create the app packages and launch the certification kit is missing. I checked that my developer account is signed in, enabled developer mode on the machine, reinstalled VS checking to install Universal App development and Windows 10 SDK. Nothing enables this menu. No more options to create apps are present, just Blank App, I had more templates available under VS2013.

It is also weird that when I select to edit appmanifest it never displays the editor, just the XML, it seems like the whole app store environment is disabled. The project is not being recognized as an app.

Another big problem is that the designer does not display the XAML files to see the graphical elements. I get an error screen with tons of errors about null exceptions.

I need to port some 8.1 apps to Win10 Universal and these set of problems are driving me crazy.

Any help more than appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, this combination of problems makes it seem like your computer is in a not so good state - maybe try reinstalling windows? As for the certification kit, can you launch the kit without using Visual Studio (search for Windows App Cert Kit) in the start menu and see if it is there)?

Also, for Universal Windows Platform, only blank templates are available. You can find many samples here though. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I am using a fresh Windows 10 installation from official source, no betas, no RC, just the Windows 10 that probably million of users are getting. I think that the problem is focused on Visual Studio. What I have discovered is that if I create a Blank App but with JavaScript instead of C# everything seems to be ok and Store menu option is available as well the other issues. I would say the problem is Blank App C#. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure why that would happen. Did you try to repair Visual Studio?

Comment: I've seen the same thing with one of my dev machines. I couldn't see the Store menu under the Project menu. Also if I double click the app manifest it opens the xml, not the designer. This was an existing app that is in source control. Same source on another machine seems to work fine.

Comment: I tried the following. Uninstalled VS Enterprise 2015, rebooted, installed VS Community 2015. Opened store app project. Store menu is not visible. Still looking for a fix. Interestingly, the recent projects on start screen where visible so not clean uninstall.

Comment: One further question... do you have the Cordova tools installed on top of the Windows 10 tools?

Comment: Possibly, I tend to install everything. I saw some threads somewhere that there are issues so have uninstalled everything I didn't need and tried VS repair. Still no store menu currently. Complete uninstall and reinstall doesn't help as it seems to leave settings somewhere.

Comment: same for me under win 8.1. Just installed an vs 2015, tried one sample project and Store is grayed out by default.

Comment: False alarm, wrong project was selected :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Fix 1: "Change" the installation to make sure the VS extensions are installed
In certain situations, the Xamarin installer might automatically un-check the install options for the Visual Studio extensions. If that's the cause of the problem in your case, you can install the missing Visual Studio extensions using the installer's "Change" command. For example, if you wanted to install the extensions for Visual Studio 2013:

Open the Windows "Programs and Features" Control Panel.
Right click the "Xamarin" entry, and select "Change".
Click "Next", then "Change".
Make sure the "Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013" option is set to install:
Enable Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013 installation option
Proceed through the rest of the installer wizard.
Possible Fix 2: Ask Visual Studio to set up the extensions again
Check if the Xamarin extensions have been copied into the Visual Studio extensions folder:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\3.1.228.0"
If the extensions are properly installed (for version 3.1.228), there will be 60 items in the folder:
List of 'Xamarin\3.1.228.0' folder contents in Explorer​
After you have confirmed that this folder looks correct, tell Visual Studio to try setting up the extensions again:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup
Possible Fix 3: Try a fresh reinstall of Xamarin
From the Windows Control Panel, uninstall any of the following that are present:

Xamarin
Xamarin for Windows
Xamarin.Android
Xamarin.iOS
Xamarin for Visual Studio
In Explorer, delete any remaining files from the Xamarin Visual Studio extension folders (all versions, including both Program Files and Program Files (x86)):

C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio 1*.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin
Also check in the "VirtualStore" directory to see if there might be any "overlay" copies of any of the extension directories:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore
Open the registry editor (regedit).
Look for this key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls
Find and delete any entries that match this pattern:

C:\Program Files*\Microsoft Visual Studio 1*.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin
Look for this key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1*.0\ExtensionManager\PendingDeletions
Delete any entries that look like they might be related to Xamarin. For example, here's one that used to cause trouble in older versions of Xamarin:

Mono.VisualStudio.Shell,1.0
Reboot.
Reinstall the current stable version of Xamarin using the individual installer (.msi) download link under Xamarin.iOS -> Windows or Xamarin.Android -> Windows on http://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads.
Possible Fix 4: Repair Visual Studio installation
Open the Windows "Programs and Features" Control Panel.
Right click the relevant Microsoft Visual Studio entry, and select "Change"
Click the "Repair" button in the Visual Studio dialog that opens.

link : https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1643349-missing-visual-studio-extensions-after-installation